# python .T.dot() numpy syntax understanding

Tags: python, numpy

Might I ask more info about this syntax?

```
l1.T.dot(l2_delta)
```

I was under the impression np.dot(x,y) took two arrays as parameters

Does this line means transpose of l1 and then multiply l2_delta still?

Thanks

Comment: .dot() can be called as a method on an ndarray - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.dot.html np.dot is the equivalent function - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html

Comment: That's an array method `np.ndarray.dot`, not the module-level function `np.dot`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding of what your code is doing is correct.

Your confusion is coming from the fact that there are two kinds of numpy "dot" functions:

- The numpy dot function, which takes two arguments:

  - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html
- The dot function that belongs to numpy ndarray objects, which has only one argument:

  - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.dot.html

Similarly, here's the ".T" function that belongs to ndarray objects: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html

Comment: A function that 'belongs to an object' is usually called a method.

Answer (score 3):

`vec.dot(vec2)` == `np.dot(vec, vec2)`

So yes, you're correct.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.dot.html

Answer (score 1):

Here good example from Codecademy ML Course.
[image]